# Spring SpEL expression evaluation for an application yml property

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I am trying to derive a value for a property in my application.yml config file using Spring SpEL expression, but it looks like the the expression is not getting evaluated.
Here's my application.yml snippet:

```
spring:
  profiles: local
  cloud.client.hostname: abc.pqr.xyz.lmn.westus.env.company.com
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        instance:
            metadata.tags.environment: local
            metadata.tags.dc: "#{'${spring.cloud.client.hostname}'.split('.')[4]}"
        url: http://localhost:8079
```

During runtime, the property `spring.boot.admin.client.instance.metadata.tags.dc` is being evaluated to `abc.pqr.xyz.lmn.westus.env.company.com.split('.')[4]` and expectation is that it be evaluated to `westus`.

What am I missing?

Comment: normally in java `split()` takes a regex as input, not a single character. maybe `'.'` needs do be escaped. try with `.split('\\.')`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SpEL is not supported in `application.yml`.

Use `@Value("#{'${spring.cloud.client.hostname}'.split('\\.')[4]}" ) String property` in code instead.